# How to achieve html formatted strings in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs. Here I have a string fetched from database and it is in html form like this

```
$scope.data = '<p>this is first line </br> this is second line</p>';
```

and when i dispaly it like

```
{{$scope.data}}
```

It actually come as it is without html formatted like

```
<p>this is first line </br> this is second line</p>
```

But I want as

```
this is first line
this is second line
```

Comment: use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 3):

Use $sce:

```
$scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>this is first line </br> this is second line</p>');
```

HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
```

Comment: but i want to use it inside ng-repeat inside <td>.Is it possible with this?

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                                                <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ 'name': 'text' }" sortable="'name'">
                                                    {{user.post_title}}
                                                </td>
                                                <td data-title="'Content'">
                                                    {{user.post_content}}


                                                </td> 
</tr>

Comment: I actually wants to use this in {{user.post_content}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular's $compile tool, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).